# Why visual studio and gcc produce different outputs for c++ code

Tags: c++, gcc

I have the following C++ Program:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <ostream>

using namespace std;
ifstream input("input.txt");
long long N, C, D;
long long a[100000][4];
long long b[100000][4];
int case_number = 0;
long long chosen_machine;

long long max(long long v1, long long v2)
{
    // returns the maximume value between 2 values
    if (v1 > v2)
        return v1;
    else
        return v2;
}

long long f_recursive(long long cash, long long i, long long i_chosen, int e)
{
    if (i == N - 1)
    {
        if (e == 0) //we dont buy the current machine
        {
            return (cash + (D-b[i][0]+1)*b[i_chosen][3] );
        }
        else //e==1 and we will buy the current machine
        {
            if (cash < b[i][1]) //we cant buy it
            {
                if (i_chosen == -1)
                    return cash;
                else
                    return (cash + (D - b[i][0] + 1)*b[i_chosen][3]);
            }
            cash = cash - b[i][1] + b[i][2];
            return (cash + (D - b[i][0])*b[i][3]);
        }
    }

    if (e == 1) //we are going to buy the machine
    {
        if (cash < b[i][1])
        {
            //we cant buy it so we keep the current cash and go to next machine
            return max(f_recursive(cash, i + 1, i_chosen, 1), f_recursive(cash, i + 1, i_chosen, 0));
        }
        cash = cash - b[i][1] + b[i][2] + (b[i + 1][0] - b[i][0] - 1)*b[i][3];
        return max(f_recursive(cash, i + 1, i, 1), f_recursive(cash, i + 1, i, 0));
    }
    else // e==0 and we wont buy the machnie
    {
        if (i_chosen == -1) // if we did not buy any machine before (we still own no machine)
        {
            return max(f_recursive(cash, i + 1, i_chosen, 1), f_recursive(cash, i + 1, i_chosen, 0));
        }
        cash = cash + (b[i + 1][0] - b[i][0])*b[i_chosen][3];
        return max(f_recursive(cash, i + 1, i_chosen, 1), f_recursive(cash, i + 1, i_chosen, 0));
    }
}

int read_case()
{
    //reads each case and corresponding N C D and also the machines details to array a
    string line;
    input >> N >> C >> D;
    for (long long i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        input >> a[i][0] >> a[i][1] >> a[i][2] >> a[i][3];
    }
    return 1;
}

int sort_a()
{
    long long checked[100000];
    for (long long i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        long long max = 999999999999999999;
        long long j_chosen;
        for (long long j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            if (a[j][0] <= max && checked[j]!=1)
            {
                max = a[j][0];
                j_chosen = j;
            }
        }
        b[i][0] = a[j_chosen][0];
        b[i][1] = a[j_chosen][1];
        b[i][2] = a[j_chosen][2];
        b[i][3] = a[j_chosen][3];
        checked[j_chosen] = 1;
    }
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    int exit_condition = 0;
    while (!exit_condition)
    {
        read_case();
        if (N == 0 && C == 0 && D == 0)
        {
            exit_condition = 1;
            continue;
        }

        if (N==0) // there is no machine, so simply output the dollar we have
            cout << "Case " << ++case_number << ": " << C << "\n";
        else
        {
            sort_a();

            cout << "Case " << ++case_number << ": " << max(f_recursive(C, 0, -1, 0), f_recursive(C, 0, -1, 1)) << "\n";
        }
    }       

    input.close();
    cout << "Finished, please press Enter...";
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

I am using this as input (in file "input.txt"):

```
6 10 20
6 12 1 3
1 9 1 2
3 2 1 2
8 20 5 4
4 11 7 4
2 10 9 1
4 979142410 1000000000
719554784 535235252 43212142 2
679922882 929213070 72282699 3
947550084 114776168 96759913 1
811283493 865444308 248312924 4
10 936980155 1000000000
762761567 683459202 109944378 6
686089795 734650986 45620682 4
678254540 925086416 24622261 5
807652386 596279745 140024880 9
791494729 585405092 50583956 8
655401693 691328196 82491162 3
799450676 654579438 65612488 10
580278950 624801431 68664589 2
834332323 692933073 524827737 7
101802074 760182347 3637050 1
1 10 100
50 11 9 100
1 10 100
50 10 9 100
1 10 100
1 10 9 100
1 10 100
100 10 9 100
1 10 100
95 10 1 1
1 10 100
95 10 1 2
1 1000000000 1000000000
1 10 9 1000000000
2 10 100
80 67 60 7
20 8 5 1
2 10 100
80 66 60 7
20 8 5 1
2 10 100
80 66 60 1
20 8 5 7
2 10 30
20 8 5 8
20 2 1 7
0 0 0
```

In Microsoft Visual Studio (C++), the code produces this output (it does so on Debug or Release):

```
Case 1: 44
Case 2: 1116877054
Case 3: 2353506445
Case 4: 10
Case 5: 5009
Case 6: 9909
Case 7: 10
Case 8: 10
Case 9: 11
Case 10: 999999999999999999
Case 11: 87
Case 12: 200
Case 13: 567
Case 14: 87
Finished, please press Enter..
```

On Linux (gcc g++), it produces this output:

```
Case 1: 44
Case 2: 1116877054
Case 3: 2353506445
Case 4: 10
Case 5: 10
Case 6: 10
Case 7: 10
Case 8: 10
Case 9: 10
Case 10: 1991568403
Case 11: 10
Case 12: 10
Case 13: 10
Case 14: 10
Finished, please press Enter..
```

For reference, I am trying to solve this problem:
http://docdro.id/H6fd5bs

Does anybody know or any ideas why the input and output would be different on the different compilers?

Comment: Probably relying on Undefined Behavior or Implementation Defined Behavior. I haven't been able to see it though; there's a lot of code posted here and it's not easy to follow

Comment: 1) Easiest answer for why results differ under different compilers is: undefined behavior somewhere in your code. For example: `j_chosen` in `sort_a` might be used, before being assigned a value, under some conditions. 2) Did you try stepping through your code with a debugger, to investigate, if everything works according to your expectations?

Comment: `checked` in `sort_a` is uninitialized.

Comment: Unrelated. You're frequently using `int`s where `bool`s would make more sense, at least to readers. `bool` conveys "I'm true or false." whereas an `int` could be just about anything.

Comment: `long long checked[100000] = {0};`to initialize every element to 0 instead of "unknown values" and that's also kind of a lot of memory to be putting on the stack like that.

Comment: Thank you, guys! All of you were right. The problem was unassigned variable. I just assigned the array "checked" and now it is working fine on both platforms.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In visual studio when a variable is created, its value will be zero by default but in Linux g++, the variable will be random. Hence, assigning the variables will solve this problem. This was the problem I encountered, however, there will be other issues based on the code.

Comment: Which variable? Globals are always initialized to their default value which is 0 for int types. For anything else there are no guarantees, and in debug mode Visual Studio initializes with special values, so I would expect your behavior to be different between debug and release.

Comment: Based on what I experienced, the array (int) will be initialized to 0 when creating in the visual studio, however, in Linux the elements of the array will be random. In general, always assign a value to the variable you are defining. ;)

Comment: Based on what you experienced is not the same as guaranteed by the C++ standard. In a debug build with Visual Studio your uninitialized variables will be assigned special sentinel values by the debug allocator. You didn't answer the question which was which variable did you initialize to make your program run correctly? Your self-answered question will not help anyone else without details.